# How do you filter by file type/extension using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

If I want to find just Excel files using the Microsoft Graph API. Is there a way to filter using odata $filter? By file type or name "endswith"?

I have tried odata filter on the name property using "endswith", "indexof", "contains" but I don't think they are supported (although "startswith seems to be).

Is there a place that states **exactly** what $filters are supported by the Microsoft Graph API? The docs just give a few examples and it seems like the only support odata function is "startswith".

I was able to use search as in below but I was looking for $filter support.
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drive/root/search(q='.xlsx')

Answer (score 2):

Filtering with `endsWith` is not supported for OneDrive Business Drive API. 
There isn't a simple way to look for files by extension today. You could try `search` for extension (however, it sometimes returns non-matching files/folders) -or- you can do client-side filtering. Neither options are good. I find client side filtering as the only option. This does mean you have to navigate through the pages to get a full list.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I didn't see it before. I hope they consider adding this to the API as it's a fairly standard Odata thing. It's very difficult, actually impossible, to filter by file type because search brings back unexpected results

Comment: Yes, this feature should be coming in the future. It's an important one to file the files by type.